# SQL - split numeric into 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to split some numeric keys in my table into separate columns (to help save space in SSAS, lower cardinality)

My data looks like the below..

```
LeadKey
1
2
3
5522
83746623
```

I want to split these into 2 columns... with 4 digits in each column. (where applicable, as anything 1>9999 won't have anything populated in the 2nd column)

So an example output of the above would be the below..

```
LeadKey         Split1            Split2
1                  1
2                  2
35566              3556             6
5522               5522    
83746623           8374            6623
```

How could I achieve this? I have split columns easily before using substring and a known character.. but never had to do a split like this. Does anyone have an approach to handle this?

Comment: Zero pad and use `LEFT` and `RIGHT`? What happens if a value is > 99,999,999 or < 0?

Comment: [Division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [Modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) help you. `select 83746623 / 10000, 83746623 % 10000` will give the result `8374` and `6623`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in case you have the `LeadKey` numbers as `int`.

```
select LeadKey
      ,left(LeadKey, 4) Split1
      ,right(LeadKey, case when len(LeadKey)-4 < 0 then 0 else len(LeadKey)-4 end) Split2
from   t
```

| LeadKey | Split1 | Split2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 35566 | 3556 | 6 |
| 5522 | 5522 |  |
| 83746623 | 8374 | 6623 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/omwLfrz_?hide=4)

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I used left for the Split1, and show the values past the 4th position for the Split2:
I've included a testing temporary table to hold our the testing values.
Feel free to adjust the code to work with your situation.

```
DECLARE @thelist TABLE
(
LeadKey      int
);

INSERT INTO @thelist (LeadKey)
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 35566 union all
select 5522 union all
select 83746623

select cast(x1.LeadKey as varchar(19)),
Left(x1.LeadKey, 4) as 'Split1',
(case when len(x1.LeadKey) > 4 then right(x1.LeadKey, len(x1.LeadKey) - 4)
 else '' end
 ) as 'Split2'

from @thelist as x1
```